# How do I prevent the facebook sdk from loading in parent frame?

Tags: iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an iframe that is being loaded and has an embedded facebook video. It loads the facebook sdk and then triggers it to play the video.

The problem is that loading the SDK inside the iFrame is causing the sdk to be initialized in the parent window instead of inside the frame. How do I prevent that from happening so that I can play the video in the iFrame?

(as a side note, I had thought the whole purpose of an iFrame was to prevent code inside it from modifying the parent frame, how is this happening?)